# DAX - Querying Data with DAX combine data from two tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I am new to DAX and am pulling Tabular Data from Analysis Services. There is a lot of data and I only want to pull certain columns from different tables in the cube. I can pull a couple of columns from one table but not sure how to combine it. Please see the screenshot below any help with writing this query would be appreciated.

For example, I want to see `[Region]` from `'Companies'` and `[State]` from `'Houses'`

[image: IMAGE EXAMPLE]

Comment: This all depends on how the data relates to each other. I still think you need 2 tables and make a realtion between the tables (what you can do in powerbi, third icon on left side bar.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the fact table related to Houses and Companies tables. Lets assume it's name is Fact, then you may use SUMMARIZE to retrieve just the combinations of the columns that exists in Fact table like follows

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZE(
    'Fact',
    'Houses'[State],
    'Companies'[Region]
)
```